# state and city select box like national breakdown page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to simulate a state and city select box exactly like national breakdown site. Here is the url : https://www.nttsbreakdown.com/ntts/programs/main/main.php

On the left part of the web page, if you select a state, the city select box shows "loading data" then pop up the list of the city in that state. You can search a city name in the city select box. Also the city select box is automatically selected. I am trying to use JQuery chosen to simulate but not quite like it. First of all, I have to click to choose a state and then click to choose a city. Not like national breakdown site, you only need to click on the state and city automatically drop down and you can search in the city select box. I am wondering if they are using something else instead of JQuery chosen. If anyone can point me to the right direction, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Since they are dynamically loading the list of cities, they are using jQuery-AJAX and a REST API like backend (in PHP) to supply the list of cities.

Comment: I know how to load a getcity.php by using javascript and to show the content of the list of city. But I can not figure out how to make the city select box automatically drop down with the search function once the user select a state. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Topics that will lead you into the right direction will start with Async requests via JQuery/Ajax implementation or XHR. Great resources at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest).

Essentially you'll have an onchange event for the drop downlist 'select element' and once it changes in that function you would do a request to your service that will pull down data for the cities based on that id or somesort of criteria. That XHR will have a callback so you don't freeze your browser. But in the mean time while the request is being handled and getting the information you can pop a loading gif over the section that will be loaded (or this could be done before the XHR request), in the callback function of the XHR you can remove the loading gif and poulate the correct data in the drop down list and webpage a.k.a request complete.

--EDIT added idea where to start

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="state" list="stateList" name="stateList" />
        
        <datalist id="stateList">
            <option value="Texas" />
            <option value="Arizona" />
        </datalist>
        
        <input id="city" list="cityList" name="cityList" />
        
        <!-- this data list is populated from an ajax request /java script once the state is selected you do a query based on its selected value -->
        <datalist id="cityList">
            <option value="something1" />
            <option value="something2" />
            <option value="something3" />
            <option value="something4" />
        </datalist>
    </body>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var inputStateHandler = document.getElementById('state');
        var inputCityHandler = document.getElementById('city');
           
        inputStateHandler.addEventListener('input', function() {
            inputCityHandler.focus();
            inputCityHandler.open(); //this is what you need to figure out open does not exist as of yet.
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do you make the city select box automatically selected and searchable?

Comment: what do you mean by searchable? a select box is a drop down list. Not sure I understand exactly what you mean by searchable. But to make it focused you do so via it's DOM property so document.getElementById("selectboxID").focus(); using the items id to set focus onto the object.

Comment: searchable means that you can input the first letter of the city and the select box automatically change to only show the list of the cities start with the letter. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm guessing you are looking for something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_datalist). it's a different element and is not supported on older browsers. the input will take a list attribute in which case the datalist's id will be the link.

Comment: Something like it. But look at this web site https://www.nttsbreakdown.com/ntts/programs/main/main.php   It works on older browser. When you choose a state, the city select box automatically selected and opened and you can search. Check it out and I want to do exactly like that. Maybe you can give some ideas how they did it. Thanks a lot!